# Create Shortcut via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder if it's possible to make a shortcut with multiple targets, because my code doesn't work with 3 paths. Below code and screenshots.

Can you help? Thank you all in advance

https://ibb.co/pWs87P9

I want something, like in the screenshot below (I've done it manually)

https://ibb.co/9tH4Rx5

C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "C:\Temp Logs\app.vbs" "C:\Temp Logs\try.bat"

```
Sub aa()


Dim sShortcutLocation As String


sShortcutLocation = "C:\Temp Logs\AA.lnk"


With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(sShortcutLocation)
    .TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe ""C:\Temp Logs\app.vbs"""
    .Arguments = "C:\Temp Logs\try.bat"
    .Description = "Shortcut to the file"
     .Save
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying use one target (notepad.exe) and pass other files as arguments to it?

Comment: Yes, like in the shortcut, which I've created manually